# Distributin Ruby Code on Multiple Threads with Batches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, parallel-processing

This is a kinda stupid question but, but I'm having some issues distributing the correct amount of data that a worker needs to process.

For a bit of context, I have 60 Resque Processes (workers), each is strictly set to have only **1 thread** (it is a must in this context).

E.g. `worker1: bundle exec env rake resque:workers QUEUE='queue_1' COUNT='1'`
...
`worker60: bundle exec env rake resque:workers QUEUE='queue_60' COUNT='1'`

Each of the workers/threads (because each worker has one thread) needs to process an amount of data. And the problem I have is finding the right amount of data needed to be processed by each worker.

My Input

`nr_rows` - Number of Data needed to be processed
`batch_size` - We get the data in batches
`nr_workers` - Number of workers

E.g.

`nr_rows - 3_700_000
batch_size - 50_000
nr_workers - 60`

Currently, I'm using the following code:

`

```
  per_process = ((nr_rows / batch_size) / nr_processes.to_f).ceil
  start = 0
  finish = per_process - 1

  (1..nr_processes).each do |queue|
    (start..finish).each do |i|
       # Spawn worker here on this 'queue' and process data from #{i *50_00} to #{i * 50_000 + 50_000} -- Note: 50_000 = batch_size 
    end

    start += per_process
    finish += per_process
  end
```

`

The problem is the following if we print out the `start` and `finish` for each `queue` we will get the following output.

`nr_rows - 3_700_00`
`batch_size - 50_000`
`nr_workers - 60`

`queue 1 - start 0 finish 1
queue 2 - start 2 finish 3
...
queue 27 - start 72 finish 73
queue 28 - start 74 finish 75
...
queue 59 - start 136 finish 137
queue 60 - start 138 finish 139`

My problem is that queue 60 will start processing data from 
`138 * 50_000` to `138 * 50_000 + 50_000`, which is way out of bounds.

Starting from queue 28.. all workers will get out of range.

Any suggestions?

Thank you and sorry if it's a stupid question.

Comment: It's not a stupid question but I'm not understanding why you need to do this. You need inputs to get processed in their exact order under all circumstances?

Comment: @maxpleaner Thank you for the replay! It does not require the inputs to be executed in the same order but it requires a start and end bound. For example, start at 10 finish at 11, [10, 11] and then we have another worker start at 1 finish at 2, [1,2]. The order in which the bounds are executed it's not important just the start and end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I suggest :

```
# Variable Initialization
nr_rows = 3_700_000
batch_size = 50_000
nr_workers = 60

num_batches = (nr_rows / batch_size.to_f).ceil
# Generation of the batch info (first_row...last_row) in this form : [first_row1, last_row1/first_row2, last_row2/first_row3, ..., first_row_n]
batch_bounds = Array.new(num_batches) { |i| i * batch_size }
# We make sure the last batch goes to the last row : ..., first_row_n, last_row_n]
batch_bounds << nr_rows

# We calculate the exact amount of batches to distribute for each process
per_process = num_batches / nr_workers.to_f
# Since we can't distribute a non-integer batch we keep the remaining info to make sure we'll distribute the batch correctly
remaining = 0
# batch index in the batch_bounds array
batch_index = 0

# Distribution of the batches amongst all worker
nr_workers.times do |process_index|
    # Adjust the batch remaining
    remaining += per_process
    # We take only the integer part to process full batches
    num_to_process = remaining.to_i

    # We distribute the batch to the current worker
    num_to_process.times do
        # batch_bounds[batch_index]...batch_bounds[batch_index+1] corresponds to the rows to process in the current batch
        # send batch_bounds[batch_index]...batch_bounds[batch_index+1] to process_index
        puts "#{process_index} : #{batch_bounds[batch_index]...batch_bounds[batch_index+1]}"
        # We update the batch index
        batch_index += 1
    end

    # We remove the batch we processed of the remaining batch to process
    remaining -= num_to_process
end
# Just in case
if batch_index == batch_bounds.size - 2
    # process the remaining batch
    puts "#{nr_workers-1} : #{batch_bounds[batch_index]...batch_bounds[batch_index+1]}"
end
```

This code looks a bit complex but the ultimate goal is to balance the batche to the worker and make sure that if the last batch is not a 50_000 row batch, we send a tinier batch to the last worker.

With this code, if there's more batches than worker some worker will get 2 or more batch, if there's less batch than worker, some worker won't get batch at all.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, It worked like a charm. I did a couple of tweaks and changes to fit my use case but it is exactly what I needed! Thank you again!